# Itext , pdf created couldn't be open opened by adobe reader

Tags: pdf-generation, itext, adobe-reader

i wanted to create pdf with Itext , everything works until i've made the runnable jar . 
Adobe reader shows that message : "Adobe Reader could not open xxx.pdf because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example. it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)." 
And here is my code :

```
try{
         Document document = new Document();
         writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE) );
         document.open();
         makeBackground(document);
         makeText();
         makeTable(document);
         afterTable(document);
         document.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a 90% chance that an exception is thrown in the following lines:

```
makeBackground(document);
makeText();
makeTable(document);
afterTable(document);
```

This causes your application to create a PDF with a PDF header, but without a trailer (the trailer is written when you `close()` the document).

If you don't tell us anything about the error message you're getting from the `Exception`, nobody 
will be able to help you.

Possible causes:

- outside the runnable jar, you have external jars in your CLASSPATH that can't be reached from your jar.
- outside the runnable jar, you have access to external resources (font files, images,...) that aren't accessible when you run the jar.
- ...

In any case: this isn't an iText-related problem, because you say that it works until you make the runnable jar. As it works outside the runnable jar, there probably isn't a problem with the code.

You probably have a configuration problem: you did something wrong while creating it (for instance: you created the iText.jar yourself and you forgot to insert the `.afm` files).
It is very hard to solve such configuration problems remotely, especially since you're not telling us which exception was thrown, which size the PDF has (could be 0), if the PDF ends with `%%EOF`.

Comment: Well, that explains why Adobe Reader tells you the file is not a PDF file ;-)

Comment: yes , at least we have confirmation that it's a configuration problem

Comment: But i didn't find where the problem come from ,  the itext jar  is in a package : librairie .

Comment: Well, without more info, nobody can tell you what's causing the problem. If the file has 0 bytes, there *must* be an exception that is thrown *before* or *at the very start* of `document.open()`. If you don't tell us more about that exception, we're at a loss.

Comment: Remove all of your `try\catch` wrappers and let the exceptions happen.

Comment: there's an IOEXCEPTION